# IntegerUpDown Binding Issue

Tags: wpf, data-binding, mvvm, wpftoolkit

In my WPF app, I have a datagrid with a IntegerUpDown control displayed in a column and its bound to a property in my viewmodel:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Qty">
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <toolkit:IntegerUpDown Minimum="1" Maximum="999" Value="{Binding SelectedQuantity, Mode=TwoWay}" Increment="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,0,0,0" Name="integerUpDown1" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

It appears to be only 1 way binding. The value thats initially set in my viewmodel is shown in the control, but when I change the value of the control it doesn't update the viewmodel. I've made sure to change the value of the control then press tab or enter to lose focus and trigger the update but still no luck. My viewmodel is pretty simple, and here's the SelectedQuantity property

```
public int SelectedQuantity
{
    get
    {
        return _selectedQuantity;
    }
    set
    {
        if (value != _selectedQuantity)
        {
            _selectedQuantity = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("SelectedQuantity");
        }
    }
}
private int _selectedQuantity;

public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

private void OnPropertyChanged(string property)
{
    if (PropertyChanged != null)
    {
        PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property));
    }
}
```

It may have something to do with Automapper? I use Automapper to map my model to my viewmodel. I thought initially that I maybe needed to use Automappers "Ignore" on this property, but after trying that the same problem persisted. The SelectedQuantity is not a property in my model object. Maybe it has something to do with DataGridTemplateColumns?

**Edit**
It appears nothing is actually bound correctly with the datagrid (although other controls in the View are bound correctly) :( This is how I'm populating my `ObservableCollection<ProductViewModel>` object

```
public void Search()
{
    _viewModel.SearchResults.Clear();
    List<ProductViewModel> searchResults = Mapper.Map<List<Product>, List<ProductViewModel>>(_productService.SearchProducts(_viewModel.SearchValue));

    foreach (ProductViewModel pvm in searchResults)
    {
        _viewModel.SearchResults.Add(pvm);
    }
}
```

**Edit 2:**

My DataGrid is bound to the `ObservableCollection<ProductViewModel>` object like so `ItemsSource="{Binding SearchResults}"`  I am seeing the items properly in the DataGrid, changes just aren't being reflected in the viewmodel. SelectedQuantity is a property in ProductViewModel.

Comment: Is there a collection being bound to the DataGrid?  If so is SelectedQuantity a member of the object in the bound collection or is it in the view model of the window/control hosting the datagrid?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are mixing bindings.  The datagrid is probably bound to an ObservableCollection (if it isn't, I would start there).  The item context at the row level is the individual object, which is the object that should have SelectedQuantity property in order for your XAML to work.  If it is on your encompassing viewmodel, this won't work as multiple rows will be bound to the same property and I don't think it will give you the effect your looking for.

Try adding some code to see if the value is being sent once you exit the row:

```
<b:Interaction.Triggers>
    <b:EventTrigger EventName="RowEditEnding">
        <b:InvokeCommandAction  Command="{Binding RowEditEndingCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding }"/>
    </b:EventTrigger>
 </b:Interaction.Triggers>
```

Comment: In the View constructor I set this.DataContext to my ViewModel. The ViewModel contains an ObservableCollection which I then Bind to the DataGrid ItemsSource like so ItemsSource="{Binding SearchResults}". I do see data populated in the datagrid, changes just arent reflected in the viewmodel

Comment: Thie line 'Value="{Binding SelectedQuantity, Mode=TwoWay}"' implies that SelectedQuantity is on the ProductViewModel.  Is that where it exists or is the SelectedQuantity property on the same viewmodel that contains 'SearchResults' as a property?

Comment: Have you tried adding 'UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged' to the Value binding?

Comment: I'm not too familiar with Interaction.Triggers but I've added it to the DataGrid, and used this <ei:CallMethodAction TargetObject="{Binding}" MethodName="Submit" /> then created the Submit function on my ProductViewModel... it never gets hit